# How to create an Internet connection using cable in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: internet-connection

I downloaded the new version of Ubuntu,
but I do not know how there furnish an Internet connection.

It would be very nice
if someone would take the trouble to explain to me all the required steps in detail.

If it helps further: it's LAN

## Wie erstelle ich eine Internetverbindung mit Kabel bei Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

ich habe mir die neue Version von Ubuntu heruntergeladen,
aber ich weiß nicht wie ich dort eine Internetverbindung einrichte.

Es wäre sehr nett,
wenn sich jemand die Mühe machen würde und mir alle dazu notwendigen Schritte ausführlich erklärt.

Wenn es weiter hilft: es ist LAN

Comment: Please only use English at Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Just to clearify: you plugged the cable in and it does not work? -- Deutsch: Nur um sicher zu sein: Du hast das Kabel eingesteckt und bekommst keine Verbindung zum LAN?

Comment: More details needed...Did you use windows before on this connection? how did you connect then? was there dialling/connect with username & password button involved or was it automatic?

Answer (score 0):

The ubuntu documentation has a description on [Lan networking](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-help/net-wired-connect.html).

If you have problems, maybe you can use the installed help on your computer (to access use Superkey+F1, on my keyboard this superkey is actually a key with the windows logo).